# What is a safe way to check for a protocol response

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsurlconnection

Here's a scenario:

A view controller pushes a new controller to the nav controller.  This child controller creates a model that uses a NSURLConnection.  When this connection finishes it will make a call like the following:

```
[self.delegate modelDidFinishParsing:self];
```

What is the safe way to produce this code?  Right now, I have this code and it crashes in a certain situation:

```
if ([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(ModelDelegate)]) [self.delegate modelDidFinishParsing:self];
```

The situation when it crashes is when the view controller that owns the model is popped from the stack before the model finishes.  Should I make the model an ivar so that the controller releases it in its own `- (void)dealloc` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your check, you could make sure the delegate isn't `nil`

```
if (self.delegate && [self.delegate conformsToProtocol...]) [self.delegate modelDidFinishParsing:self];
```

Comment: Well, personally I would use [self.delegate respondsToSelector..] rather than [self.delegate conformsToProtocol..], but other than that, it should work.